# YUIcompressor missing semicolon before instruction

Tags: javascript, java, maven

I have an issue when I am trying to compress my Javascript file with yuicompressor-maven-plugin version 1.4.0

In my Javascript file I have this :

```
if (true) {
  let y = 5;
  console.log(y);
}
```

And during the goal "compress" I have :

> missing ; before statement
>                       let y = 5;

What I am doing wrong ?

see here : [let syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 1):

My feeling that the **error message is wrong** - code is wrong too but for some other reason...

See the compilation result on [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=if%20(true)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20y%20%3D%205%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(y)%3B).

> Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined

`let` variables are scoped by `{}`

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code it was a bad copy/paste. Without minifying the Javascript the code works perfectly. It's only when I am trying to minify the that I have this error message